# Married Couples in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek

It just occurred to me that hardly anyone in any of the series is married! What's up with that? O'Brien is married, Dr Crusher and Cpt Sisko are widowed, Tom Paris and B'Elanna Torres get married - those are the only examples I can think of. Other than the characters listed, and not counting marriages that take place *after* the time of the respective series (Crusher and Picard) or alternate reality stories (Troi and Worf), are any recurring characters in any of the series married?

Comment: Consider that most regular characters in any Star Trek series are are typically on long away missions for extended periods of time, all the time.

Comment: @GorchestopherH Though TNG's Enterprise has family living quarters largely so that married crew members can bring their families on those long away missions.

Comment: You overlooked the wedding of Riker and Troi at the start of 'Nemesis'.

Comment: Shout out for http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_House_of_Quark_%28episode%29

Comment: "Honey, I'm home!" - 'tho that was dating, not marriage

Comment: Sulu was married and had a daughter [see Star Trek: Generations].  Bones was married as well. Worf was married to Jadzia and Capt Sisko was married twice (the second time to Capt Kasidy Yates).

Comment: I can't believe every single one of the answers so far ignores the o'Briens -- they got married onscreen in TNG, had a kid in-episode later on, and their married life featured in more than one DS9 episode.

Comment: @Shadur That's 'cause they were mentioned in the question!

Comment: It's unethical to 'sample' the local fauna if you have previous 'engagements'. The writers liked to keep their options open ;)

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo: We know Sulu had a daughter. Do we know he was married?

Comment: I do believe that Spock's parents remained happily married the entire series. (At least in the tv series.)

Answer (score 26):

Adding to the other answers' lists, and concentrating on major crew members.

**Voyager:**
 - Janeway was engaged prior to her mission to the Badlands.
 - Tuvok is married with children and a granddaughter.
 - Ensign Wildman is married (and pregnant with Niomi) at the beginning of the show.

**Enterprise:**
 - Phlox is married (3 wives).
 - T'Pol was married, with that later annulled

**TOS:**
 - Spock was briefly married, with marriage annulled (what is it with the Vulcans?)
 - Kirk was engaged, but chose Starfleet career over marriage.

**DS9:**
 - Some of Dax's past hosts were married (both as male and female.)
 - Quark was briefly married to Grilka, who then divorced him.
 - General Martok's wife is an important figure in his house, and had to give her blessing for Jadzia to marry Worf.
 - Gul Dukat had a wife (s?) and children.

And there are many "alternate timeline" episodes with possible/alternate futures to fill a book with marriages, divorces, and so on:
 - Voyager's Doctor is seen with his wife in "Endgame".
 - Chakotay is told to have married Seven of Nine, also in "Endgame".
 - Tom Paris and Kes were married and had a daughter (who then married Harry Kim.)
 - Beverly Crusher married Jean-Luc Picard (and then divorced him [but kept the last name]).
 - The whole Defiant crew paired up and married each other when they got stranded in the past on a distant planet.
 - Jake Sisco married and divorced when his father got phased out of reality.
 - etc.

Comment: Sarek and, errr..., Mrs. Sarek?

Comment: Aside from the three wives, each of whom had two co-husbands with him I believe, Phlox also had 5 children (two daughters and three sons).

Comment: Also seems like much of the crew on NX Enterprise hooked up during the alternatish timeline while in The Expanse, though not sure how much of that involved marriage. I just thought the possibility might make an addition to your last section. Excellent answer by the way.

Comment: @ThePhoton [Amanda Grayson](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0040549/bio)

Answer (score 23):

How about Spock's parents, from the original series?  Ambassador Sarek and Amanda Grayson.

[image]

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I find that downvote illogical.

Answer (score 22):

Apparently life on a space station (DS9) is where people go to settle down.

- Dax and Worf get married.
- Rom and Leeta get married.
- Sisko married Kasidy Yates.
- Riker and Troi were married in Nemesis.

How recurring do you want? Ishka (Rom and Quark's mother) partners up with Zek. You can see a few others at [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Wedding)

Comment: I need to watch that series from the start, I don't remember much of it at all. I didn't know Dax and Worf got married, and I don't even know who Rom and Leeta *are*!

Comment: Don't forget Lwaxana Troi and Odo also got married - after Lwaxana got divorced from that Tavnian, Jeyal.

Comment: Tuvok is married to T'Pel...!

Comment: For one offs we have Helena and Sergey Rozhenko (Helena actually appears twice), and Robert and Marie Picard (they appear once but are mentioned in Generations). Also, Sulu likely got married at some point, seeing as he had a daughter (appeared in Generations).

Comment: Also in TNG Nurse Ogawa was engaged to another officer, although their marriage is never mentioned that I know of.

Comment: I had not remembered Riker and Troi were married in Nemesis.  To be honest Nemesis is sort of a blur.

Answer (score 7):

Star Trek is patterned after old time explorers (when it isn't being a "wagon to the stars" :)

Many of those people were NOT married, due to the nature of ocean travel at the time (months/years between being onshore)

Comment: Admittedly it's the wron universe, but in Star Gate career-military-folks do not merry. Since SG is portraying "the real" army, one could imagine that it is that way in reality too and that this "reality" inspired the scarcity of married career-officers in Star Trek too.

Comment: @Einer I would be willing to bet that there a lot of career officers serving in the current armed forces who would disagree that they don't get married.

Comment: @Xantec - Star Trek wasn't modeled on 1990s army though. More 1700s-1800s Navy

Comment: @DVK Maybe (TNG era seemed more modern). But my comment was more in response to comparing it to SG. That indubitably was modeled on the modern military.

Comment: @Einer: But already in TOS, we saw marriages between crewmembers. Even though it ended in a sad way, it didn't seem to me like the ceremony that was planned in [Balance of Terror](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Balance_of_Terror_%28episode%29) was an extraordinary event.

Answer (score 7):

The DS9 marriages were already mentioned by Jack B Nimble.

Further to this,

- There was the on-screen wedding reception of Will Riker and Deanna Troi at the start of 'Nemesis'.
- Dr Kate Pulaski had also been married a few times previously.
- Dr Leonard McCoy was divorced.

There are also a few *near* marriages:

- Spock and T'Pring
- Deanna Troi and Wyatt Miller
- Lwaxana Troi and Campio

Marriage did come up a few times in the various shows.

Comment: Lwaxana was actually married to Odo for a time during that episode, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I know - I added that comment to Jack B Nimble's answer about the DS9 marriages.

Comment: Lwaxana Troi and about every other male crewmember ... if she had it her way.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I can't believe I out trek the Trekkers.  Basically Roddenberry was anti-marriage, anti-religion.  Roddenberry himself was polyamorous (I.e. Nichelle Nichols & Majel Barret).  Roddenberry did not believe in traditional western marriage (and his non-exclusive marriage was a Shinto ceremony).  Basically Roddenberry had an ardent view that 21st century religion and ethics would be obsolete in the 24/25th. While Roddenberry didn't hammer this view home in TOS, he did become more dogmatic and insist upon the exclusion of religion and religious ceremony (including marriage) in TNG.

Notice the marriages mentioned above occur in TOS before Roddenberry was adamant about his philosophy, or after his death (in TNG, DS9).  Don't believe me, watch Trek Nation or Chaos On The Bridge.

Short answer, Roddenberry was against religion (and marriage) in the 24/25th century.

Comment: This is a nice out-of-universe explanation why there are so few instances of marriage in Star Trek, but the question is asking, in-universe, if "any recurring characters in any of the series [are] married?".

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to list everything that everyone else covered. I will mention Chapel was engaged too, since nobody else has.

Now, In Balance of Terror, Kirk was about to officiate the wedding of Angela Martine and Robert Tomlinson. Tomlinson died in the episode and it never happened but some of the dialogue over the course of TOS suggests that it wasn't uncommon. Bones said that there's no regs against romance. Martine and Tomlinson talk about one of them transferring departments so they weren't in the same chain of command.

In one of the novels, Kirk and his girlfriend shared quarters but weren't married, she later died but that's neither here nor there.

Also in ST as a whole, people don't always change their names, unless it's specifically stated, you don't know who's married (i.e. Spock, his 'wife' and the shock of the bridge crew).

Answer (score 3):

The Star Trek series are adventures. They primarily focus on encounters with other cultures and phenomena. There are stories which are more character and relationship driven, and certain characters have relationship arcs (sometimes confined to individual episodes, sometimes spanning seasons), but they are more about defining/filling in the characters who participate in the adventures. The Galaxy class NCC-1701-D had families aboard, which at least implied married couples. Since this ship is about science and generally working and living in space (it has a school for the crewmembers' kids), it must be assumed that shipboard life must be (mostly) no more hazardous than Earthbound life, so families could/would choose to bring their families along and live aboard, but this is mostly implied.

As already stated (with examples) in other answers, many characters are either married, have been married, get married, are engaged, get engaged, or initiate a relationship within the span of the series in which they appear. Their relationships don't necessarily get a lot of screen time because it would draw focus away from the adventure aspect of the shows. Nevertheless, a lot of episodes do feature relationships between certain characters and their significant others.

To put it another way, Star Trek is space opera, not soap opera.

Comment: `(it has a school for the crewmembers' kids)`Although why such a little kid has to take calculus is beyond me...

Answer (score 1):

John Boychuk is right, the best explanations are Doylist.  The show is about the adventures the characters have and they aren't bringing their husbands and wives along for that.  You could have the husbands and wives sit at home and just talk things out with their spouses...but it's more economical to have the characters talk to other regular characters.  Keiko was only in a handful of episodes over the whole run of DS9, the writers just didn't get around to using her much.

Answer (score 0):

Miles and Keiko O'Brien? Had kids and all (with the wildest surrogate motherhood ever, a brilliant way to cover up an actual pregnancy)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question already mentions that O'Brien is married.